# IE8 alternative to window.scrollY?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I'm trying to determine how many pixels down I've scrolled using `window.scrollY`. But this isn't supported in IE8. What is the safe, cross-browser alternative?

Comment: Use a library like Mootools or jQuery to handle browser abstractions for you if at all possible.

Comment: Aren't the cross-browser versions to scrollX and scrollY, document.body.scrollLeft and document.body.scrollTop?

Comment: ^^^^^ It's [***pageYOffset and document.body.scrollTop***](http://help.dottoro.com/ljnvjiow.php)

Comment: @adeneo Is it ok if I link to that article in my answer please?

Comment: @Zenith - Sure, example 4 on that page shows a cross browser way to get the scroll position, even accounting for zoom !

Answer (score 110, accepted):

The cross-browser compatible version for `window.scrollY` is `document.documentElement.scrollTop`. Please see the 'Notes' section of this piece of [**Mozilla documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.scrollY?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.scrollY) for a full, detailed workaround in IE8 and before.

[**As mentioned here**](http://help.dottoro.com/ljnvjiow.php),  `pageYOffset` is another alternative to window.scrollY (note though that this is only IE9+ compatible).

In regard to the link above, check **Example 4** for a fully compatible way to get the scroll position (it even accounts for zoom as @adeneo mentioned!) using `document.documentElement.scrollTop` and `document.documentElement.scrollLeft`.

[**Here, try out the example for yourself!**](http://help.dottoro.com/external/examples/ljnvjiow/scrollTop_4.htm)

Comment: `document.documentElement.scrollTop` gives 0 in Google Chrome 40

Comment: @McX This is because of an ongoing Chrome bug that is yet to be resolved (but judging from the replies I've seen, it's in the process of being fixed) - https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=157855

Comment: January 2016, still not fixed.

Comment: Nov 2016, still not fixed.

Comment: April 4 2018, fixed :)

Answer (score 15):

If you don't have to use it a lot, just do:

```
var scroll = window.scrollY //Modern Way (Chrome, Firefox) 
|| document.documentElement.scrollTop (Old IE, 6,7,8)
```

Comment: this works, though I don't think you need the second one (window.pageYOffset).  While it works, all older IE browsers support the `document.documentElement.scrollTop` way of getting the scroll position.  Newer IE browsers ("Edge") support `window.scrollY`, as mentioned in the MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.scrollY

Answer (score 5):

If you're using jQuery, I used $(window).scrollTop() to get the Y position in IE 8. It seemed to work.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a valid reason for not just using a library to handle this kind of base functionality, don't hesitate 'not to re-invent the wheel'.

[Mootools is open source](https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Element/Element.Dimensions.js), and you can just 'steal' its implementation, relevant snippets:

```
getScroll: function(){
    var win = this.getWindow(), doc = getCompatElement(this);
    return {x: win.pageXOffset || doc.scrollLeft, y: win.pageYOffset || doc.scrollTop};
}

function getCompatElement(element){
    var doc = element.getDocument();
    return (!doc.compatMode || doc.compatMode == 'CSS1Compat') ? doc.html : doc.body;
}
```

These 2 are the core of deciding which compatibility mode your current browser it has, and then whether to use `window.pageYOffset` or `document.body.scrollTop` based on that or even `document.html.scrollTop` for really ancient buggy browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Niels' answer, I come up with a slightly more compact solution when just the Y coord is needed:

```
function get_scroll_y() {
    return window.pageYOffset || document.body.scrollTop || document.html.scrollTop;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on Mozilla, and answers above, I have a created the functions below to more easily get the coords:

```js
var windowEl = (function () {
    var isCSS1Compat = ((document.compatMode || "") === "CSS1Compat");
    function scroll() {
        return { left: scrollLeft, top: scrollTop };
    };
    function scrollLeft() {
        return window.scrollX || window.pageXOffset || (isCSS1Compat ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft);
    };
    function scrollTop() {
        return window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset || (isCSS1Compat ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop);
    };
    return {
        scroll: scroll,
        scrollLeft: scrollLeft,
        scrollTop: scrollTop
    }
})();
```

According to the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.scrollY?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.scrollY), as cited by lifetimes above, the The `pageXOffset` property is an alias for the `scrollX` property, so is stictly speaking not necessary.

Anyhoo, usage is:

```js
var scroll = windowEl.scroll();
// use scroll.left for the left scroll offset
// use scroll.top for the top scroll offset

var scrollLeft = windowEl.scrollLeft();
// the left scroll offset

var scrollTop = windowEl.scrollTop();
// the top scroll offset
```

Tested & works on Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Edge (8-Edge), IE (7-11), IE8 on XP

Answer (score 0):

In angular, we use:

```
  var windowEl = angular.element($window);
  scrolldist = windowEl.scrollTop();
```

Comment: that is [jQuery's scrollTop](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) anyway..

Answer (score 0):

window.scrollY & window.scrollX works fine in all modern browers like (Chrome, FireFox & Safari) but does not work in IE so to fix the use window.pageXOffset or window.pageYOffset.

Here is a sample code I wrote to fix ie issue so that the programmatic scrolling works in all browsers including IE

```
if((window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset) >= 1100){
   //alert('Switch to land');
    $('#landTrst').trigger('click'); // your action goes here
}else if ((window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset) <= 900) {   
    //alert('Switch to Refernce Letter');
     $('#resLet').trigger('click'); // your action goes here
}
```