# set scrollTop cross browser

Tags: javascript

I'm having issues setting scrollTop cross browser. I did a search which said to use the solution below.

I've currently got:

```
var body = document.documentElement || document.body;
body.scrollTop = 200;
```

this works in IE, not chrome

if I switch it round:

```
var body = document.body || document.documentElement;
body.scrollTop = 200;
```

it works in chrome, not IE

how to fix this?

Comment: What about jquery:
`$("html, body").animate({scrollTop:0}, '500');`

Comment: sorry i should of said, I'm not using jquery

Comment: document.documentElement.scrollTop is cross browser? [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618785/ie8-alternative-to-window-scrolly/16618863#16618863)

Comment: doesn't work for me in chrome. e.g: document.documentElement.scrollTop = 200; console.log(document.documentElement.scrollTop) , returns 0

Comment: In Internet Explorer 6 and later, document.body and document.documentElement exist, so the first you put is the one the code would use. However, browsers are treating assigning the viewport to an element differently, which is why the code works on one browser and not on the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some interoperability issues and incompatibilities in this area. In order to avoid user agent sniffing (and to ease migration to the standard API, where `document.documentElement.scrollTop` controls the viewport, rather than `document.body.scrollTop`), a new API was implemented in modern browsers.
Basically, have a function for scrolling that does this -

```
function scrollViewport(top, left)
{
 var eViewport = document.scrollingElement
 if (eViewport)
 {
  if (typeof top !== "undefined")
  {
   eViewport.scrollTop = top;
  }
  if (typeof left !== "undefined")
  {
   eViewport.scrollLeft = left;
  }
 }
 else
 {
  // Do your current checks or set the scrollLeft and scrollTop
  // properties of both of documentElement and body, or user agent
  // sniffing, if you must.

  // Example -
  // var scrollTop = 200;
  // Chrome, Internet Explorer and Firefox, I think.
  // document.documentElement.scrollTop = scrollTop;
  // Safari, at least up to version 11, I think.
  // document.body.scrollTop = scrollTop;
  // Or just (I am not sure I recommend this)...
  // window.scrollTo(0, scrollTop);
 }
}
```

Read the [Opera article](https://dev.opera.com/articles/fixing-the-scrolltop-bug/) for more information.

Comment: thanks, i detected the userAgent string to see if the browser was chrome to set the 'body' variable, instead of using both statements as i use it in a lot of places, but your answer helped me

Comment: No, no, no, never detect the browser! Especially since they have fixed their implementation recently and your code may break soon! Feature detect instead. I am not sure about your specific case, but, generally, this should work, assuming you know the page can actually be scrolled (higher than the viewport) - `document.documentElement.scrollTop = 1; var useDocumentElement = (document.documentElement.scrollTop !== 1);` and check that variable instead of the browser.

Comment: Note that if you browser detected this incompatibility, your code is now broken. Chrome has fixed this interoperability issue.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
var body = document.documentElement;
body.scrollTop = 200;
```

It should be cross browser, unless you've done something wrong, like missing the html-tag or something like that.

[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_document_documentelement.asp)

Comment: doesn't work for me - document.documentElement.scrollTop = 200; console.log(document.documentElement.scrollTop); returns 0 always, but works in ie

Comment: and you are not in quirks mode? you have set a doctype?

Comment: @JimmyRare Chrome (and maybe Safari) fixed their implementation recently, but if you are using this code in older versions (or older mobile browsers), WebKit still always uses `document.body` for the real `scrollTop`. :(

Comment: True, sorry about that. I just took it for granted IE was the issue. :D
Generally when I want to ensure cross browser compability I use a library/framework to avoid the pain.