# Semi-transparent header becomes opaque on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I am attempting to display 5the header of my website at 50% opacity (the header and navigation will overlap a slideshow that's behind it). When the user scrolls down the page, I want the header area to remain locked to the top of the webpage and the opacity be removed. I found an example that I was able to modify. It works in all browsers except IE. Does anyone know of a work-around for IE?

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
 document.body.classList[
  window.scrollY > 20 ? 'add': 'remove'
 ]('scrolled');
});
```

Here is the working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/SEH5M/524/

Cheers!

Comment: Which version of IE are we talking about? It might be an issue with supporting the CSS3 opacity feature - check this article for cross-browser opacity: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/

Comment: Also I'd suggest you put the transition rule inside the #header for a smoother effect

Comment: Internet Explorer 11

Answer (score 0):

In IE you need to use:

```
 **window.document.documentElement.scrollTop** instead of **window.scrollY**.
```

find more here:
[IE8 alternative to window.scrollY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618785/ie8-alternative-to-window-scrolly)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I swapped out the code but unfortunately it's still not working in IE. The semi-transparent background does not turn solid black when the user scrolls up and down. I am trying this on IE 11.

Comment: Indeed it is working in codepen (but not in jsfiddle)!! I am going to move forward with it. Thank you again Saar!