# window.pageYOffset vs window.scrollY on IE11

Tags: javascript, dom

Window.scrollY does not show the correct top-scroll value on IE11 but Window.pageYOffset, the alias of Window.scrollY, works as expected. I find confusing the fact that the alias works better than the original property. Could somebody help me understand why? :[

Note - I'm not interested in finding a cross-browser compatible version. The point is that I want to know why an alias on IE11 is not working the same as the value which is being "tracked". I'm not sure if I should deeply focus on some different "aliases" on IE...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IE8 alternative to window.scrollY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618785/ie8-alternative-to-window-scrolly)

Comment: Just because the specification says one is an alias of the other, does not necessarily mean that browsers will have implemented it according to specification ...

Comment: OK but is it possible that IE has a function that looks the same as alias in specification but works in other way - surprisingly work, in opposite to the alias with the same name...

Answer (score 51):

Window.scrollY is not supported in IE(11 or below). Window.pageYOffset works on "all" browsers including IE9-11. Window.scrollY works on "all" browsers except IE.

IE9 and below should (in most cases) not be supported anymore because using them means no security updates for browser or OS, but [IE8 alternative to window.scrollY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618785/ie8-alternative-to-window-scrolly) explains you can use `document.documentElement.scrollTop` for lower versions of IE.