# Trigger a function after scrolling x pixels from the top

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, dom-events

I would like to trigger something once (and only once) a user has scrolled down 100 pixels from the top.

In the past I was given this code, but it doesn't seem to be working?

```
window.onscroll = function() {
  var scrollLimit = 100;
  var scrollValue = document.body.scrollTop;
  if (scrollValue >= scrollLimit) {
    alert("x")
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the replies.
Someone posted the following code (which I slightly edited), with : document.documentElement.scrollTop  and it works fine. 



I dont know why it had been deleted : doesnt work with ie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong property here.

Instead of `scrollTop` property you need to use the **[`Window.scrollY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY)** property.

This is how should be your code:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
  var scrollLimit = 100;
  if (window.scrollY >= scrollLimit) {
    alert("x")
  }
};
```

## Note:

**`window.scrollY` compatibility issues with `IE`:**

Unfortunately `window.scrollY` doesn't work with IE browsers, for IE you can use `window.pageYOffset`as  a replacement, but it always gives hundreds rounded values `(100, 200, 300, ...)`.

Otherwise you can check the [accepted answer **here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618785/ie8-alternative-to-window-scrolly) it uses `document.documentElement.scrollTop` as a workaround.

Comment: It seems that "Window.scrollY" is not compatible with ie

Comment: @jeremy Yes, but you can use `window.pageYOffset`as  a replacement in IE, but it always gives hundreds rounded values, or you can check the [accepted answer **here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618785/ie8-alternative-to-window-scrolly) it uses `document.documentElement.scrollTop` as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var scrollValue = window.scrollY;
```

Answer (score 1):

`scrollTop` will give you the offset between the top of the element and the top of the document. Since the body of a html document by default starts at the top of the document, body.scrollTop always stays 0 unless you specifically used css to make the body not start at the top.

So you have to use `scrollY` instead of `scrollTop`. If the browser you use does not support `scrollY` ( eg. IE ) you can try `pageYOffset`.