# Javascript event (add style) on height scroll for Chrome, FF, IE

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to trigger an event on scroll at certain height. 
Specifically yo add a style, and my code works in Chrome, but not in IE.
Can anyone assist?

```js
myID = document.getElementById("subnav");
var myScrollFunc2 = function() {
  var y = window.scrollY;
  if (y >= 150) {
    myID.className = "subnav stick";
  } else {
    myID.className = "subnav unstick";
  }
};
window.addEventListener("scroll", myScrollFunc2);
```

```css
.subnav {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.stick {
  top: -62px;
  position: fixed !important;
}

.unstick {
  position: relative !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="subnav">123</div>
```

Comment: `y = document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.body.scrollTop;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IE8 alternative to window.scrollY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618785/ie8-alternative-to-window-scrolly)

Answer (score 0):

IE [doesn't support `scrollY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY).

You can do this instead:

```
'scrollY' in window ? window.scrollY : document.documentElement.scrollTop
```

Answer (score 0):

I've came accross an answer searching on SO

```
var scroll = 
    window.scrollY // Modern Way (Chrome, Firefox)
 || window.pageYOffset // (Modern IE, including IE11)
 || document.documentElement.scrollTop // (Old IE, 6,7,8)
```

Credits goes to [this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618785)

Comment: In that case, it's a duplicate and should be flagged as such.